# User id not being stored in a session

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
    require '../connect.php';

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
    $query->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
    $query->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password']);
    $query->execute();

    if($row = $query->fetch()){
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        header("Location: ../index.php");
     } 
  }
?>
```

When someone logs in it only stores the username and not the id can someone please help me.

Comment: Is `session_start();` loaded? If not, do. It's required when using sessions and must be inside all pages using them.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect `$row['user_id']` to contain?  Look at your `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password
```

You're not *selecting* the `user_id`, so you don't *have* a `user_id`.  You probably want to select it:

```
SELECT user_id, username, password FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password
```

Also, side note... ***Never*** store user passwords in plain text.  There is ***no*** reason to ever do this.  Passwords should be 1-way hashed and ***not readable by anybody***.  Please stop being grossly irresponsible to your users.

Comment: PSA; sessions are not started

Comment: @DarylGill Normally I would agree, but the OP indicated that the username is successfully stored in the session.  Which suggests that the session is started outside of the posted code.